# Create a basic data set by specifying a range of values

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to create a single variable for my the purpose of my macro function. What I want to do is simple. I want to create a dataframe with a single variable with a range of character values. For example:

```
forecast
fore1
fore2
fore3
fore4
```

I am aware of the some of the ways this can be done with the input and datalines statements, however, the issue I am having is that I want to use fore1-fore4 to generate the data in this dataframe so that it will generalize to my macro function.

Comment: You're using R terminology, but it sounds like you want a simple data set but it's not quite clear what you need. Also, please include what you've tried so far. I mean a DO loop with an explicit OUTPUT statement will do this easily but it may not generalize depending on what you're trying to do further on.

Comment: If you're coming from R to SAS be careful of diving in to macros too soon. A lot of things don't need macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you literally want that data set, it could be as simple as this.

```
data want;
    do i=1 to 4;
        forecast = catt('fore', i);
        output;
    end;
    keep forecast;
 run;
```